# Frequent errors running TFS-2013 with git

Tags: git, tfsbuild

We have TFS-2013 configured to use a git repository. All works fine most of the time but we are getting intermittent build errors - they even seem to become more frequent over time.

This is what we can find in the build logs when the problem occurs:

> Exception Message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Os
>   (Error).
>
> Could not remove directory. File
>   'C:/Builds/1/MyTool/MyTool_CI/src/.git/objects/pack/pack_git2_a02380'
>   cannot be removed: The process cannot access the file because it is
>   being used by another process.
>
> (type LibGit2SharpException)
>
> Exception Data Dictionary:
>
> libgit2.code = -1
>
> libgit2.category = 1

What could cause these errors..?

Comment: We've seen intermittent reports of this and we're looking into why this is affecting some users.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Let us know if you need more input - problem always go away when manually retriggering the build..

Comment: We're getting this issue often as well. I thought it was related to running multiple builds at the same time (I've only enabled GIT on 1 build agent for now to minimize the problems unfortunately)

Comment: @cacau Well yes I think so if I make sure only one build runs at the same time I don't seem to get the issue at all. A check-in triggering 5 builds at the same time is guaranteed mayhem.

Comment: I am getting a problem similar to this.  It happens only on CI build if I kick off the same build manually it works.  The kicker is.  I am not using Git?  Its failing the same way for all 40 ci builds.  It started when I installed VS2013 update 2

Comment: @MarkMonforti There's Update 2 already? RC? From comments we've got from our local MS representatives I was hoping this update would solve the issue..

Comment: Update 2 doesn't fix the issue for us..

Comment: @EdwardThomson Any official response or feedback regarding this problem..?

Comment: @cacau sorry about the delay; I just saw a note from a coworker that we have a root cause for the problem (it was very difficult to track down), I will let you know when I have an ETA for a fix

Comment: @EdwardThomson That's good news - cheers!

Comment: This error also started to happen here after update 2, the first build we tried failed, and since at least 2 out of 3 is failing.

Comment: The problem is always reproducible for me when there are 2 build agents(on the same computer) are pulling the sources from git. Update: I'm using TFS 2013.2 Express with VS2013.2 installed.

Comment: Can anybody confirm this issue has now been fixed with **Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013, Update 3**?  
One of the fixes listed for TFS in this release sounds promising: "*Concurrent builds of the same Git repository may fail.*"

Comment: @cacau No, unfortunately we still have the issue with TFS2013.3 and VS2013.3

Comment: @Zidad Actually - we don't see this issue any more with the .3 updates..!

Comment: @cacau I'm seeing it now (never before) after applying the TFS 2013 Update 4 :(

Comment: @John ...for us it was there all the time since installing a year ago :-/

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in progress, as seen by [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a2af3201-e8ee-4c66-99de-21c5f9dfb1bf/git-errors-vs2013-rtm?forum=TFService):

> Can you repaire your VS2013 RTM and try again? Also, you can can see event viewer to see if there any useful info or have a try on other machines as I mentioned above.

Comment: The problem related in your link is different (network error vs. filesystem error).

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when the issue happens, *Process Explorer shows the open file handles from TFSBuildServiceHost. **Restarting the service appears to be a workaround.***

We never had this issue before we introduced several builds for different branches within one repository. Then one day the build failed with exception:

```
Exception Message: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. (type AppDomainUnloadedException)
Exception Stack Trace: 
Server stack trace: 
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_clone(RepositorySafeHandle& repo, String origin_url, FilePath workdir_path, GitCloneOptions& opts)
at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)
at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitClone.GetRepository(String repositoryUrl, String workingFolder, Boolean checkoutSubmodules)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
```

After this the issue started appearing from time to time until I restarted TfsBuildServiceHost. TFS 2013 U4.